# How to enable SSL in MySQL on Windows?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ssl, mysqladmin

I'm a student doing a project which uses JDBC and MySQL (on Windows).
I have an application with connects to a MySQL server on a remote host.

To have a secure connection, I found this : http://www.razorsql.com/articles/mysql_ssl_jdbc.html

but SSL is disabled in my MySQL server.

I already tried enabling it using this:
http://mysqlopt.blogspot.in/2010/05/using-ssl-connections-with-mysql.html

but it's not working.

I just want to make this connection to be a little more secure in a simple way, any ideas?

Comment: 'it's not working' is not an error message (or error description) of any sort.  Could you be a bit more specific please?  Probably adding the relevant configuration values and how do you try to connect would help a lot.

Comment: ssl is still diabled.

Comment: OK, let's see once more.  What do you try (which commands do you issue)?  What do you get (error messages, output etc.)  We don't have the crystal ball delivered yet (shameless plagiarism here!)

Comment: look this question this maybe helpful! :

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11353/mysql-ssl-disabled-on-windows